# Posts URL structure like site.com/category/the-post-title

Tags: categories, url-rewriting, urls, plugins-url

I'm new with `wordpress` and I would like to understand better if it's possible to create pages with an url based on the `category` and then the `post title`, so:

something like `http://mysite.com/category-name/the-post-title`
or `http://mysite.com/category-name/12345` (the post id)
or `http://mysite.com/category-name/12345/the-post-title`

does exist some plug-in do this or should I consider other ways like `url_rewrite` to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, any of those are possible and configurable under `Settings > Permalinks`. Have a look at the [Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) page for other possibilities.

One thing to note though, it's suggested to add a number at the beginning of your permalinks to reduce the number of rewrite rules WordPress has to generate to resolve all of your URLs.

The permalink strings for your examples would be:

```
/%category%/%postname%

/%category%/%post_id%

/%category%/%post_id%/%postname%
```

Comment: thank you, it's very simple, I'll take a wider look to the online guide, it's easy too!