# Custom Path/Folder behind a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, directory

I have not find any attempt to start yet, so the question is - is it possible to add at path behind the output of a custom post type?

This means: I have a custom post type "movies" and fill it with several categories and other attributes/ratings/whatever.

Their Path will be: www.test.com/movies/themovie1, .../themovie2, ... and so on

What I need to add is an automatically generated page that takes input from both movies and will generate behind EACH movie, just as it was a child element of "movies" in the hierarchie:

www.test.com/movies/themovie1/alternatives

and even "better":
www.test.com/movies/themovie1/vs/themovie2
and vice versa:
www.test.com/movies/themovie2/vs/themovie1

Those have to be created automatically - I plan to create JSON files as a source for them as all the possible combinations being written into the database via insert_post would kill the database with millions of pages - I already know the architecture I need, issue is: can I create a single-movies.php that creates those sub-folders? 
(Possible idea: using a GET Query and have it transformed instead of ?vs=xyz?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Posts URL structure like site.com/category/the-post-title](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16968/posts-url-structure-like-site-com-category-the-post-title)

Comment: Thanks, but categories are unfortunately not what I am looking for. I want to have a single-post-type.php that has a variation of itself in a directory (this is why I was asking if it is possible to transform the GET_ Variants of such a file to a /get/variation1, /get/variation2 - maybe this is rather a generic PHP question if there is no solution using the WordPress Permalinks / .htaccess modification available?